# How to create user defined functions using code first in ABP?

Tags: ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate, .net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I want to create some user-defined functions using code first approach in abp framework.

I have created stored procedures xyz by adding xyz.sql inside

> EntityFrameworkCore\Migrations\Stored Procedures

folder, But not able to find a way to create a function, please help.